# Infinite loop in SQL?

Tags: sql, infinite-loop

There is some way to implement a infinite loop in SQL?? I was thinking on some like a select inside another one, recursively... (Maybe im talking foolishness)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do a recursive infinite loop with a CTE:

```
;with rec as
        (
        select  1 as n
        union all
        select  n + 1
        from    rec
        )
select  n
from    rec
```

By default, SQL Server would stop at 100; you can make it loop forever with:

```
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: You'd need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION = 0)` to make this infinite, right?

Comment: it turns out this only works on SQL 2005 or later - for SQL 2000:

Answer (score 13):

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
SELECT 'This will go forever'
END
```

Comment: I didn't mean to put that comment on your answer, sorry. lol I was just clarifying that a declarative statement (which yours is not) can't be recursive. Your answer is fine.  :-)

Comment: @Richard - I caught that, no worries :)

Answer (score 4):

This should work in oracle

```
select * from (select level x from dual connect by  level >=0)
```

the outer select is needed to avoid some optimizations which happen with some combinations of client and database.

Not completely sure if the `level >= 0` part works as intended, since normally you would use this only with something like `level <= 50` to get a fixed number of rows.

Comment: I found this solution very useful in automated tests of logic which is responsible for proper killing long-running queries. Without it, I would have to find some large table or cross join many tables, which depends on data in database and leads to unstable and fragile test.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine why you would want to do this, but it's going to depend on your *implementation's* (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...) supported loop constructs.

For example, in SQL Server, you would write an infinite loop the way you would in any imperative language. Roughly:

```
DECLARE @x INT = 0
WHILE (@x = 0)
BEGIN
  PRINT @x
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @number INT = 3

WHILE (@number = 3)
BEGIN
    PRINT @number
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an infinite loop with a declaritive language like SQL because the compiler's won't let you. You will get error messages and/or it just won't run.

You need to do something like what JNK suggested, using SQL to write something sequential.